# Different alignment in different browsers

Tags: jquery, css, browser, drop-down-menu, alignment

I have a nav menu which is a series of divs, alternately a div with a menu link and then a 'menu separator' div which contains a 2px wide 'separator bar' image. The width of the separator divs is 24px so they form proper separations.

On some of the 'menu link' divs I have a regular hover dropdown with `<\li>`'s etc. Using Jquery, I make the width of the `<\li>`'s in the dropdowns the same width as its parent div on the menu, and then I add 24px (so it extends and aligns with the 2 separator divs' separator images) and add left positioning so it appears that the dropdown's borders are extending from the separator bars.

In Firefox, everything's fine. But in Chrome and IE, sometimes it's fine and sometimes it's not: Depending on the content of the main 'menu link' div from which the dropdown comes down, sometimes the dropdown is mis-aligned by sometimes one pixel, sometimes like 10 pixels. In FF it displays right every time, no matter what the content of the menu link div. In IE and Chrome, it depends on the content. eg. "Artwork" in the menu link div might mean that the dropdown perfectly lines up, but then "Artwork Shop" in that same div might mean the dropdown is off by a pixel or two. But in FF it's all fine...

Does anyone have any suggestions why this might be, or what might be a fix? Do the browsers display different letters with different pixels? Is jQuery getting different widths for some reason in IE/Chrome than FF?

My code is a bit messy and contains images and isn't on the Web yet so I can't easily show examples yet...

**Edit:** You can see an example, and how it doesn't display the same in all browsers, and with different content, at: http://jsfiddle.net/jaslfpihdaddle/aFAF9/7/ . I'm hoping someone will tell me how stupid I am, read the manual, and it's all easily fixed! ;)

Comment: Welcome to web development!  Though without code, not much we can help with.

Comment: add code to pastebin.com. Maybe the CSS is the problem...I cannot give you a verdict in your trouble :)

Comment: Check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) to know that how to ask a question well..  and create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) link if you are asking some question regarding `css`, `javascript` or browser related..

Comment: Thanks Niranjan Kalas - http://jsfiddle.net/jaslfpihdaddle/aFAF9/7/

Comment: wow havent seen a meesed up code like this before... try to only use one type of styling. css-file, styletag, jquery.css(), inline-style. i prefer css-file ;)
its good for you to find your problem at your own first and then ask here.

Comment: Thanks ;) 
It's a work in progress... once I've finished the design, obviously all the css will get stuck in classes and put in an external stylesheet. 

If I could find the problem on my own, then I wouldn't have asked here... not the most helpful comment...

Comment: If you stick an alert() in the code to get it to alert() the outerWidth() that jQuery is using to set the widths, it seems that in IE, even using 1.7, is getting different values to FF, Chrome and Safari. I think this is the problem... can anyone suggest what to do to fix this? Do I just stick in something that will use a different value if the browser is IE? Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that margin:auto was ruining it in IE. So I'm going to make jQuery make the div that the dropdown was in centred on the page instead of margin:auto, and everything will be ok! :)

(But IE still gets different width()s to FF, Chrome and Safari...)